# How to add this kind of facebook navigate controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, three20

[image: facebook link]

Ad you see in red, it's a name, and can navigate to another page (not a http url link) by click action. I guess it is a button, but I don't know how to hide button border (or rect). Or any other way can implement this kind of effect?

A name or a word, can click and navigate to another page (not a http url link). UIButton? TTButton? UILabel? TTLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is how to make this sort of 'invisible button' work out, you could simply use a custom type button set to the correct frame over the bit of text you need to be clicked;

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

On the click event of this button, you may define the process of moving to the next page or view, by say either adding it on as a subview or pushing it in via a navigationController.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably `TTLabel` or something like that because FB app uses Three20. I'll give you the non TT approach since I'm not familiar with the TT APIs.

You can indeed have a `UIButton` placed on top of a `UILabel` (you can do `button.frame = label.frame` in order to have it exactly the same size and position).
Obviously the button needs to be 'invisible. You achieve this by using a 'Custom-type button' , calling the class method:

```
+ (UIButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)type;
```

Passing the constant `UIButtonTypeCustom`, and then setting the target and action you desire: